# Is it possible to exclude specified GET parameters in apache access logs?(by W7 develop enviroment)

Tags: java, apache

There has a security hole hidden in apache's log, such as if you input a URL about

```
http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123
```

into the browser,then the **access.log** will complete record it so this is a security question because it recording the security parameter:

```
cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123
```

Now,I want to control my log printing, if I execute a url which not including security parameter such as **http://localhost/meeting/op.do**, access.log must record it, but if I input a url which incuding security parameter such as:

```
http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123
```

then access.log should not record it, What should I go to achieve?

I have tried a method that sitting log variable about **SetEnvIf** and **CustomLog** ,but it does not work:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(https?://.+\\?([^=]+=[^=]+)+)" dontlog 
CustomLog logs/access.log common  env=!dontlog
```

bucause my app request type is get, so the Request_URI can not get the parameter, if you execute a URL:

```
http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=admin&password=pass
```

the Request_URI is **http://localhost/meeting/import.php**, so this method can not success.

Do you have any useful method or Suggestions? I will vary appreciate it if you sovle this problem, thanks. I want remind you that my develop environment is W7, not linux, not support shell.

### **********************************************************************************************

----**Problem has changed!!!**----

Now,not only I want to control my log printing but also it will make the parameter replaced with *symbol, if I execute a url which not including security parameter such as:

```
http://localhost/meeting/op.do,
```

access.log must record it, but if I input a url which incuding security parameter such as

```
http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123,
```

then the regular expression replacement must work and it will sove:

```
http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=****&password=****&userName=****&meetingID=****,
```

into logs,What should I go to achieve? remind:My develop environment is W7.thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Request_URI` does not include the query_string so it will never match.  You need to use `mod_rewrite` to set the environment variable.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (password=)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=dontlog:1]
CustomLog logs/access.log common env=!dontlog
```

Comment: Great! are you online?thakns for you response,but it still can not work in my pc, and I don't know what the code means about RewriteRule ^ - [L,E=dontlog:%l],can you make a explain for me? thank you once again.

Comment: I try it again by you method,but can not work,when I restart my apache,it show warning:"The request operation has failed".

Comment: Hi h0tw1r3：I need your help,your method is very great,but I can not make it work in my computer,the code below is **perl** code?`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (password=) 
RewriteRule ^ - [E=dontlog:1] 
CustomLog logs/access.log common env=!dontlog 
`;if so,I should to Configurate perl regular expressions environment,is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just changing your app to use a POST request to handle anything that needs a password a simpler solution? This here is exactly why you shouldn't use GET requests for anything you don't want logged.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but I think the request type can not change in apache server,because it depend on your application page,so,what shold I do?

Comment: Right, I was suggesting that this isn't a bug in apache, but a bug in your application, and that the application should be fixed.

Comment: yes,but I don't know why the engineer use GET method  in the application coding in my company?Generally speaking,GET is not good than POST,so I don't know why